Ubuntu 24 Failed add network profile and connect to wifi
I am currently using ubuntu 24 on dell XPS desktop 8960. I have issue with the network setup. First, in the settings, it can detects all available Wi-Fis, but once I click to connect, it fials and switch to the cable network page (does not even ask for passward). With wired network, I failed to add network profile, but I can have internet access. Every time I tried t create a new wired network profile, it fials.
I initially was having issue with no ethernet connection after upgraidng. BUt I added the line below to the NetworkManger.conf file in /etc/NetworkManager, and I got internet connection through wire, but facing teh problem described above.
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet
Does anyone have the same issue? Can anyone help me please? Thanks!
